# displaying an image in mat form

Tags: opencv

I am trying to read an image in mat form in opencv and display it.
the code compiles fine but when run gives runtime error and the image is not displayed.
here is my code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<cv.h>
#include<highgui.h>
#include<iostream>
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

void main()
{
    Mat Img;
    Img=imread("C:/Documents and Settings/image1.jpg");
    cvNamedWindow("Image",CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    imshow( "Image", Img ); 
    cvWaitKey(0);
}
```

Could anyone please tell me where am I going wrong?

Comment: What does the error say? Is there a valid image in the path given to imread ?

Comment: It's a "debug error",saying that "the application has requested the runtime to terminate in an unusual way". the window opens but the image is not displayed @Barshan Das

Comment: And I want to ask one more thing,since I am new to openCV so could you guide me which data format is more effective for image processing so that I would focus on it...@Barshan Das

Comment: 1. Your code looks fine to me. It successfully ran in my machine. Make sure that you are giving proper path of an image file. 
2. What do you mean by "data format"? I could not understand.

Comment: there is Ipl* format and there is this matrix format. I've experimented with the former one it has been easier for me but the mat format is giving me hard time,so I was wondering which data format is better for image processing so I would focus on that one...@Barshan Das

Comment: Ipl is obsolete. People everywhere say to use Mat format. I do not know much about their difference. You can search in google for that. From my starting I am using Mat and there has been no problem with it.

Comment: Ok If the code compiles fine that means I've done the configurations right???@Barshan Das

Comment: Precisely yes. If there was problem with include header file then that had been reported at compile time. If the program could not link the library files it had been told at run time. But as you said, in your program a window opens but no image is loaded then it is problem with the image file itself. You can make sure of it by removing the imshow() and printing a simple "hello world" there. If then the runtime error does not occur, the image file must be the culprit.

Comment: ok here is what appears at the console:OpenCV Error: Bad flag (parameter or structure field) (Unrecognized or unsupport
ed array type) in unknown function, file ..\..\..\..\ocv\opencv\src\cxcore\cxarr
ay.cpp, line 2476
@Barshan Das

Comment: and yes,once I commented the imshow() function the code ran fine but...

Comment: Don't you have to give path like this? : "C://Documents and Settings//image1.jpg".  
I dont know yours but it doesnt work for me without double backslashs.

Comment: No,normally the single backslash works...but I've tried your way too and the result is still the same:(@Horizon1710

Comment: Ok, I don't know why it was not working on me with one slash.
Btw, I don't have opencv on my computer now so can't try codes. 

Img = imread("C:/Documents and Settings/image1.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);

Could this be the problem not giving the channel info to mat image? Or else it appoints a default value? I'm not sure.

Comment: I was giving the value of the image color and it's not working...@Horizon1710

Comment: This is backslash -> (\) and this is forwardslash (/)
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slash_%28punctuation%29
Backslash is used for escape chars. So in file path we have to use \\ if we need to use \. This is not the case for forward slash /. So we do not need to use //. only / is sufficient. Your console error message states that the image file can not be found. Try some invalid path name and see yourself that the same error occurs. Make sure to use a VALID IMAGE FILE PATH. Also check if there is no permission issues. The program should have the permission to access to the desired file.

Comment: Oops, in my previous comment backslash vanished. And I can not edit the comment. So this is backslash-->\

Comment: After certain experimentation with the code I've found out that the error lies with the "imread()" function...I loaded the image in Ipl format,converted it into Mat form and everything went ok,I am using vs2008,what compiler are you using and could it be a compiler based issue???@Barshan Das

Comment: @Barshan Das Thank you for the information. From now on, no confusion about slashes, I've learnt something today, thanks to you :)

Comment: @Aayman Khalid : That's strange. Mat itself is sufficient to load and display images. I do not know why you are having that much hec. I am using VS2010 , OpenCv 2.4.3.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably `imread()` is failing. You will know for certain unless you start checking the success of the functions, such an important thing to do when you code.

There's a couple of reasons why it might fail:

- You don't have permission to access the file.
- The path is wrong.

In your case, it's probably the first. So change your code to:

```
Mat Img;
Img = imread("C:\\Documents and Settings\\image1.jpg");
if (Img.empty()) {
    std::cout <<  "!!! Failed to open the file\n";
    return;
}
```

and notice how the path to file is different.

Comment: well the problem is with "imread()"!!!,I've tried both ways of giving the path but the image doesn't get read!and I am pretty clueless as to why that is happening...I did as you said and "Failed to open the file" is displayed@karlphillip

Comment: Pretty sure there should be a username before the file. Make sure the path exists, and you have permission to access the file.